# Install Fritz!WLAN USB Stick

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wireless-adapter

I'm unsuccessfully trying to install a Fritz!WLAN USB Stick on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian Stretch. Unfortunately, I have little experience with Linux. So far, entering

```
lsusb
```

is giving me

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN 1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
```

from which I guess that the USB stick itself is recognized and `TNETW1450` is the name of the chipset. However, the instruction from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/acx#Installation) apparently doesn't work; the step

```
dkms build -m acx-mac80221 -v git
```

is giving me the following error message.

```
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.9.41-v7+ cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.9.41-v7+/build or /lib/modules/4.9.41-v7+/source.
```

Additionally, searching

```
apt-cache search tnetw1450
```

is giving me no results. Does anyone know what to do? Is it possible to use the USB stick with Raspbian Stretch in the first place?

If it is relevant - connecting to a local network using the cable ethernet adapter works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message, `Your kernel headers for kernel 4.9.41-v7+ cannot be found`

When you compile a kernel module you need the kernel header.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

And then compile again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting the error message `E: Unable to locate package-linux-headers-4.9.41-v7`; what does this mean?

Comment: The headers is missing and they are needed for compiling the fritzing module.

Comment: The missing kernel headers were indeed missing; however, they can be installed with `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`. Sadly, installing the kernel headers didn't solve the actual problem since the driver didn't compile.